# css inset box shadow around all content

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble achieving a 4px inset box shadow border around all the content, getting the box shadow to fill the window is fine (as you'll see in the fiddle below) but as I have a fixed nav at the top, this is appearing above the box shadow (even if it was below though the shadow would scroll upwards and leave the nav without a top border).
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/WHP3M/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="header">
        <span class="header-link">LINK</span>
    </div>

    <div class="container">This is Content
        <br/>This is Content
        <br/>This is Content
        <br/>This is Content
        <br/>This is Content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
    z-index: 2;
}

.header-link {
    padding: 50px;
}

.test {
    min-height: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve the `box-shadow` around all the content, including the `.header` div? Or somehow achieve a `box-shadow` on the top, left and right side of the div to give the impression of a border around the whole site? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably apply the inset to the `body`, but you can easily achieve the same result with your code.
The trick is to wrap the `.header` and style `.header-wrapper` instead. In such way shadow border or padding are not going to affect the size of the box.

Have a look at my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4pQy/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
   .container {
        position: relative;
        padding: 50px;
        z-index: 1;
        margin-top:50px;
    }
```

Comment: What's the question and what are you answering?

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not the correct approach, the correct approach would be to do that to body with

```css
body:before {
  content: '.';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%,
  box-shadow: inset xxxxx;
  pointer-events: none
}
```

so it stays above

Also, using your code I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yYxWg/

added `margin: 4px 4px 0 4px` to the header. modify as necessary in your html.